# How to get better Typescript feedback in the case of when a nested method will "maybe" exist?

Tags: typescript

Just ran into a critical bug which I feel like could have been caught with the proper TS setup. I couldn't think of a better title, so please bear with me.

During the initialization of a widget app, which is something like a chat app that is loaded by another parent app, we do something akin to the following:

```
type TParamsRoot = {
  print: () => void;
}
type TParams = {
  root?: TParamsRoot;
}

const init = (params: TParams = {}) => {
  params.root ??= {
    print: () => console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

The idea here is that the parent app **should** pass on `params` when loading in the widget app, but in the off chance that it does not, I assign a basic value to it.

Anyway, somewhere else in the code I would invoke `params.root.print` as follows:

```
const printConfig = () => {
    params.root.print()
}
```

The first problem I had was that Typescript wasn't warning me about `params.root` possibly being undefined. I fixed this by adding `strict: true` into my tsconfig, and changing the function to:

```
const printConfig = () => {
    params.root?.print()
}
```

But this is still not enough, because I see no error, which is where the bug came from. Here, even though I'm checking for `params.root?`, I am calling `print`. The way to fix this bug is obviously to do:

```
const printConfig = () => {
    params.root?.print?.()
}
```

But how can I get Typescript to tell me that `print` may also not be a function or be undefined? It will always exist, once `init` is called, but I use this logic in a hook, which is used in a component, which is rendered before `init` is even called by the parent app, thus creating the bug.

Is my only option here to do,

```
type TParamsRoot = {
  print?: () => void;
}
```

It seems a little misleading, because if `params.root` exists, then `params.root.print` will always exist as well.

---

About the short-circuiting not working:

```
const params = {
    root: {
        
    }
}

params.root?.print()
```

The above is what I was going by -- indeed, it does short circuit. I have just encountered, that even though `root` is passed, it may not always have `print`. Problem solved.

Closing question.

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we could paste into our IDEs or run in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) in order to replicate this issue?

Comment: You might not be aware of the [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#short-circuiting) behavior that makes `params.root?.print()` not actually do anything if `params.root` is undefined.  It will not try to call undefined, or give you "print is not a function" at runtime.  If you are seeing such a problem, please [edit] to make your code example a self-contained [mre] demonstration of this that we can copy an paste into our own IDEs.  Right now if I try it myself [I cannot reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/WoM7aN) your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need to do an `undefined` check on `print` because it will always be there, as you mentioned, if `params.root` is not `undefined`.

`print` can't be `undefined`.

The `undefined` error was coming from `params.root` being undefined. Your solution is correct.

Comment: Correct, but if I try doing `params.root?.print()` when `root` is undefined, then I'd catch an error "print is not a function"

Comment: @MikeK No, you wouldn't.  Can you demonstrate that?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
const printConfig = () => {
    if (typeof params.root?.print === 'function') {
        params.root.print();
    }
}
```

This checks both the existence of params.root and ensures that print is a function before invoking it.

Or if you're certain that a value will always be non-null/undefined after a certain point, you can use the non-null assertion operator `!`

```
params.root!.print!();
```